# Why is Midrash not in the Torah

Tags: midrash, pentateuch-chumash

If midrashim are so important and add crucial historical/sociological details and ethical teachings and enrich our understanding of Hashem's wisdom, why are they not included in the Torah?

Comment: You could ask the same about most of Halacha.

Comment: If they were, we'd just have to learn a new layer of midrashim from them, right?  The point of midrash is to draw out extra meaning from the written torah, right?  So, more written torah just shifts the problem.

Comment: Right now, this question post looks like more than an argument in the middle of an unseen dialogue than a question. I think you could make this into a more valuable, answerable question by [edit]ing in your sources for "midrashim are so important and add crucial historical/sociological details and ethical teachings and enrich our understanding of Hashem's wisdom" as well as why you think that these qualities would indicate that these works *should* be included in the [written] Torah. Could you do that?

Comment: I seem to recall seeing a duplicate of this question on-site, but can't find it.

Comment: I think the premise may need to be questioned. I'm not sure midrashim add anything _crucial_. They're important in their own way, but have a different purpose than the actual text of the Torah.

Comment: To rephrase: Why is Midrash within Torah shebeal peh rather than Torah shebichsav? I'm not sure this question is answerable, except perhaps to question it premise.

Comment: They are included in the _Tora shebichsav_. That's what the story of the _Akeda_ is, for example.

Oh, but there are *more*, which are not included in the _Tora shebichsav_? Well, of course. It can't include *all* _midrashim_. It'd be humongous!