# Moshe's missing years

Tags: moshe-rabbeinu, egypt

During the years Moshe was missing from Egypt, was he travelling abroad, to Saudi Arabia perhaps or Paran? Are these missing years documented somewhere?

Comment: related: https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/45427/did-moshe-have-a-son-with-ethiopian-queen-prior-to-exodus/45428#45428

Answer (score 4):

See the Midrash [Quoted here](https://ohr.edu/7253). (Yalkut Shimoni, 1:168; Sefer HaYashar, Parshat Shemot). Moshe became the king of Kush for many years after running away from Egypt, and before he went to Midyan.

Answer (score 2):

Moshe was in [Midian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Midian) (an area east of present-day Israel, see [here](http://www.newworldencyclopedia.org/entry/Midianite) and [there](http://www.jewishencyclopedia.com/articles/10804-midian-and-midianites)) before returning to Egypt, see Shemot chapters 2-4

[Shemot 2:15](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.2.15?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> When Pharaoh learned of the matter, he sought to kill Moses; but Moses
>   fled from Pharaoh. **He arrived in the land of Midian**, and sat down
>   beside a well.

[Shemot 4:19](https://www.sefaria.org/Exodus.4.19?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)

> The LORD said to Moses in Midian, “**Go back to Egypt**, for all the men
>   who sought to kill you are dead.” So Moses took his wife and sons, mounted them on an ass, and **went back to the land of Egypt**; and Moses took the rod of God with him.